# Laravel Storage::putFileAs not saving the file even though it returns the path to that file as if saved

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```php
public function store(string $folder, $file){
       $ret = Storage::putFileAs("/application/public/storage/1/{$folder}", $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
       return $ret;
   }
}
```

Where the path to the `putFileAs` function ends up being `/application/public/storage/1/tasks/NXL-1` after feeding the variable `$folder`, but even tho the variable `$ret` in the return has the path to that file as if it worked `/application/public/storage/1/tasks/NXL-1/image.png`, when I go to that folder the file is not there. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **storeAs** method in laravel 8.

for example

```
$imageFileName =  $request->image_name->getClientOriginalname();
$request->image_name->storeAs('images/portfolio', $imageFileName, 'publicfolder');
```